# Family $L$ of circles centered in the $y=x$ line.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, circles

So I have to check that the family $L$ of circles centered in the line $y=x$ satisfies the differential equation
$$ y'=-\frac{x^2+2xy -y^2}{y^2+2xy -x^2}.$$

And then find the family of orthogonal curves to $L$.

But I am stuck in step 1. So.. I did the drawing and I got that the radius of the circle is $r=\pm \sqrt{2} x = \pm \sqrt{2}y$ and I was thinking on using the equation of a $(h,k)$-centered circle given by
$$ (x-h)^2+ (y-k)^2=r^2=2x^2=2y^2.$$

However, since the circles are centered in $y=x$ then it turns out that $(h,k)=(x,y)$ and so $0=2x^2=2y^2$ and I think this doesn't make any sense...and even more, if I tried to reaplace it in the $y'$ equation I would get that $y'=-1$.

Any guidance in the right direction is highly appreciated, even if it is just the idea on how to start, and how to tackle this type of problems.

Comment: Since the circle is centered at a point of line $y=x,$, such  a center would be of form $(h,h)$ [no need of the extra parameter $k$ you use]. So what happens if you start with the equation $(x-h)^2+(y-h)^2 = r$ and go from there? Note I don't see why in your version you go on to equate it to both $2x^2$ and $2y^2,$

Comment: You can solve your DE directly using the standard substitution $y=vx$ and get your family of solutions to equal $$\Bigg|\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}\Bigg|=C$$ These solution curves correspond to a *specific collection* whose center resides on $y=x$. There exist circles whose center resides on $y=x$ that don't solve this DE, like, for example, the circle $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=1$

Comment: Now I see my mistake, I was taking r in terms of x and y... you are right, I should be looking at some constant h. Thanks a lot

Comment: $ r = \sqrt 2 a \cos(\pi/4  + \theta)$ in polar coordinates are all circles passing through the origin, ( a =1/C  is an arbitrary constant) . Circle offset equals radius always.